# Solr 4.2 - what is _version_field?

Tags: solr, solr4

I am getting below error in my solr configuration.

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to use updateLog: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:806)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:619)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:1021)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1051)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to use updateLog: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist)
        at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.init(UpdateLog.java:245)
        at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.initLog(UpdateHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.<init>(UpdateHandler.java:134)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.<init>(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:526)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createUpdateHandler(SolrCore.java:597)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:790)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist)
        at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.getAndCheckVersionField(VersionInfo.java:57)
        at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.<init>(VersionInfo.java:83)
        at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.init(UpdateLog.java:242)
        ... 23 more
```

I wanted to know that what is `_version_field`, and why its must required ?

Can anybody suggest me on this??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `_version_` field is an internal field that is used by the partial update procedure, the update log process, and by SolrCloud.  It is only used internally for those processes, and simply providing the `_version_` field in your schema.xml should be sufficient.

If you'd like information as to exactly what is going on with `_version_`, you can visit [this website](http://yonik.com/solr/optimistic-concurrency/) to learn about the "optimistic concurrency" update process, which uses `_version_`.

Comment: Does adding this field into the Schema has any impact on the index size?

Comment: @Krunal: what do you think will happen on adding an extra attribute to each document?

Comment: @ashish, we tested this to understand the impact on index size and performance. We found no significant change in index size nor performance. So we decided to left the field into our schema for making it support partial update in future.

Answer (score 29):

add the below field definition inside "field" tag in schema.xml

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Comment: I think you mean `typr="slong"`. `long` oesn't appear to work on Solr 4.4.

Comment: actually there was no need to define version field earlier, it is mandatory when solr added feature to update document partially

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene with 4.10, 'slong' didn't work, but 'long' did.

Comment: If you need to use slong or long depends on type definitions inside the <types> element.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove it, you must also remove the transaction logging from solrconfig.xml. See the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml).